# Can sending messages by topic returns error for a single user?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to switch from one-by-one sending FCM messages to FCM topic fanout sending. When I send messages through FCM to a single device, I can get an error response that I should retry in a few seconds because the user received too many messages for a given time.

For topics, is this also a case that can happen, or are no errors thrown for single users? Should I do error handling?

Comment: "I can get an error response that I should retry in a few seconds because the user received too many messages for a given time" Are you sure of that? As far as I know there is no immediate feedback from the receiving device to the calling of the FCM send API.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, I got it from https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/ErrorCode, QUOTA_EXCEEDED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For topics, Firebase handles fan-out and delivery for you behind the scenes. You don't have to (and can't even) do anything for this yourself.

So while you may get a `QUOTA_EXCEEDED` response when you send to a topic too frequently, you won't get that response for individual client devices who are subscribed to that topic.